# awk/sed or any other way

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a file (with more than 1000+ lines) that I need to get the output in a format. 
I need to see how many lines each `thr` has. 
In below case
I have 3 `thr`s and 5,4,2 is the counts of each `thr` lines respective.

The input :

```
19608250477[thr=22321]: Res90 at
1: 0x00007f1fb38d5089 
2: 0x00007f1fb5565c79 
3: 0x00007f1fbb097775 
4: 0x00007f1fbb034a69 
5: 0x00007f1fbb035467 
19601889333[thr=19068]: Res87 at
1: 0x00007f1fc15f86c0 
2: 0x00007f1fc1a27d7c 
3: 0x00007f1fc1d0f312 
4: 0x00007f1fc1caf054 
16236545786[thr=55528]: Res67 at
1: 0x00007f1fb4959a90 
2: 0x00007f1fb557ad94
```

I need the output like below

```
thr=22321 ; Count 5 # Count number of lines for each thr ; Each content will start with number (1: and finish with some numebr  
thr=19068 ; Count 4
thr=55528 ; Count 2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F'[]=[]' '
    function print_count() {
        printf "thr=%d ; Count %d\n", key, count
    }
    $2 == "thr" {if (key) print_count(); key = $3; count = 0; next}
    {count++}
    END {print_count()}
' file
```

This uses `]` or `=` or `[` as the field separator.

Answer (score 1):

Another awk :

```
awk -F'[][]' '
  function p_c () {
    print a" ; Count "b
  }
  NF == 3 {
    if ( f )
      p_c()
    a = $2
    f = 1
    next
  }
  {
    b = $1
    sub ( ":.*" , "" , b )
  }
  END {
    p_c()
  }
' infile
```

Answer (score 1):

One more `awk` solution, which makes use of defining record and field separators:

```
$ awk -v RS="[0-9]+[[]" -v FS="\n" -v OFS=";" '$0 {gsub(/[]].*/, "", $1); print $1,"Count "NF-2}' input
```

Comment: How about : awk -F'\n' '{gsub(/[]].*/,"",$1);$0=$1" ; Count "NF-2}1' RS='[0-9]+[[]' infile